# C# "funny" issues with List<String[]>

Tags: c#, arrays, list, inheritance

I have some weird issues with List in my C# app. It must be an allocation mistake or that I'm doing something wrong (I'm average C# developer).
Let me give an example close to my lines:

```
List<String[]> MyPrimaryList = new List<String[]>();
List<String[]> MySecondaryList = new List<String[]>();
String[] array;

String arrayList = "one,two,three,four,five";
array = arrayList.Split(',');

MyPrimaryList.Add(array);
MySecondaryList.Add(array);

MyPrimaryList[0][0] += "half";
```

So now I would expect first value in the first array in MyPrimaryList to be "onehalf" and "one" in MySecondaryList.
But my issue/problem is that both lists gets updated with "onehalf" as first value in the first array in both lists.

Do you have a good explanation? :)

THANKS!!

Comment: You are adding the same array to both lists, so they are both pointing at the array element you are changing.

Comment: You are adding the same object to both list - in other words there is only one `array` you don't create copy anywhere...

Answer (score 17, accepted):

`String[] array;` is a reference type. You have added a reference to the location in memory of this object to both lists, therefore they both hold the same data.

If you need the second list to have a copy of the `array` then you can use [Array.Copy](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/k4yx47a1%28v=vs.110%29.aspx):

```
List<String[]> MyPrimaryList = new List<String[]>();
List<String[]> MySecondaryList = new List<String[]>();

String arrayList = "one,two,three,four,five";
String[] array = arrayList.Split(',');
String[] array2 = new string[5];

Array.Copy(array, array2, 5);

MyPrimaryList.Add(array);
MySecondaryList.Add(array2);

MyPrimaryList[0][0] += "half";

Console.WriteLine(MyPrimaryList[0][0]);
Console.WriteLine(MySecondaryList[0][0]);
```

This takes the source array, a destination array and length - be careful to check the array bounds.

This outputs:

```
onehalf
one
```

Since each list now holds a reference to a different array, you can manipulate the array items independently.

Answer (score 9):

You are adding the same instance of the array to both lists, so they point to the same memory structure.

If you want them to be independent then you'd need to clone them; A quick way from the top of my head would be using linq `list.Add(array.ToArray())` in one of the lists

Comment: `.Select(x => x)` is not needed since `string[]` already implements `IEnumerable<string>`.

Comment: @Eren, you are right, I did it that way because wasn't 100% sure that ToArray called on an array would return a new copy. But I checked and that is the way it works

Answer (score 7):

Arrays are reference objects so you are modifying the same collection in memory. All you are doing is essentially adding pointers to the same structure,

Have a look at this documentation

[Passing Arrays as Arguments (C# Programming Guide)](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hyfeyz71%28v=vs.110%29.aspx)

You will need to do a deep copy of the array to get the autonomy you want.

You can do this with [`Array.Copy`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.array.copy%28v=vs.110%29.aspx)

Answer (score 0):

You should create an array for each list you are working with because right now you are pointing at the same memory structure

the correct code should be:

```
List<String[]> MyPrimaryList = new List<String[]>();
List<String[]> MySecondaryList = new List<String[]>();
String[] array;
String[] secondaryArray;

String arrayList = "one,two,three,four,five";
array = arrayList.Split(',');
secondaryArray = arrayList.Split(',');

MyPrimaryList.Add(array);
MySecondaryList.Add(secondaryArray);

MyPrimaryList[0][0] += "half";
```

now your second list will have "one" and not "onehalf" as first element

Answer (score 0):

As mentioned array is a reference type and hence both list would point to the same array

---

To solve your problem use [Clone](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.array.clone%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) method..

```
MyPrimaryList.Add((String[])array.Clone());
MySecondaryList.Add((String[])array.Clone());
```

Though it would do a shallow copy of that array but it's suitable in your case